# GNU Parallel - Can these nested parallels be a single parallel call?

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I have a folder with a file for every 5 minute interval. Assuming the filename is 'Test-HHMM.png' for every file, I want to check for the existence of each file. So far here's what I have.

```
parallel "[ -f {1} ] || echo '{1} - Nope'" ::: $(parallel printf %s-%02d%02d.png\\\\n {1} {2} {3} ::: 'Test' ::: $(seq 0 23) ::: $(seq 0 5 55))
```

So there's a first call to `parallel` which uses `printf` to create a series of filenames, using 2 calls `seq` to generate hours and minutes. Then a second call to `parallel` does the `-f` test on each filename.

This seems like it could just be one call to `parallel`, where the command is a `-f` test on the result of a `$(printf)` of all the arguments. But I can't seem to get the syntax right. I also can't seem to break the command down into subcommands and then concatenate, to make things easier to read.

Any thoughts? Using `parallel` wrong seems dicey; it feels like I'd be better off using loops.

**Update**
Here's a stripped down version of my problem - looks Addtrivial but I can build up from this to what I need. I currently have this:

`parallel echo $(printf %02d {1}) ::: $(seq 1 10)`

I expect this to print

`01
02
...
10`

Instead I get

`./foo.sh: line 7: printf: {1}: invalid number
00 1
00 2
...
00 10`

No idea why. Tried many combinations of ' and " with no efefect.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

First: Are you sure this is not an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)?

If you are monitoring a dir to see if new files are made then this is better:

```
inotifywait -q -m -r -e MOVED_TO -e CLOSE_WRITE --format %w%f my_dir | parallel -u echo
```

But if you really are looking to see if the file exists, then a single loop in Perl will be way faster: GNU Parallel excels at tasks that take longer than a few ms to run.

```
perl -e 'print map {$_."\n"} grep { ! -e $_ } map { $a=$_*5; map { sprintf "Test-%02d%02d.png", $_,$a } "00"..23 } 0..11' |
  parallel echo {} - Nope
```

Here I assume you really want to do some thing more serious than `echo`. Otherwise you should simply put it in with the `map` after `print`.

Edit:

If the run time is not an issue then this is a fairly compact way to do the same:

```
parallel [ -f Test-{1}{2} ] "||" echo Test-{1}{2} - Nope ::: {00..23} ::: {00..55..5}
```

If what you want to run is more complex make a function:

```
mytest() {
  file="$1"
  if [ -f "$file" ] ; then
    true
  else
    echo "$file" - Nope
  fi
}
export -f mytest
parallel mytest Test-{1}{2} ::: {00..23} ::: {00..55..5}
```

Comment: Because OP may be unfamiliar with `perl`, I'd put the code in a multiline `.pl` and add [extra] comments to help OP understand what the script is doing. He'd be more likely to use it that way [if he understood, and therefore, trusted it enough to venture beyond the bash "comfort zone"]. This is particularly true if it's the better tool for the job [which, IMO, as a veteran `perl` programmer, it usually is].

Comment: Actually the requirement is just as I described it :) A simple bash script to list which files, in a timeseries, are missing for some reason. No perl etc. Not homework; more like reining in other devs writing 1000s of lines of code instead of just using `imagemagick`, etc. (Spoiler: they're paid by the hour.)

Comment: @CraigEstey I have to agree. I'm passingly familiar w Perl, but the script as written doesn't really do me any good. Sorry to be unappreciative.

Comment: @BeanTaxi No worries. Seems like you want to monitor directory and catch "gaps". I'd do that [in perl] using `opendir/readdir` in a _loop_ with a 5min sleep [could be done in bash, too]. Why parallel at all? As time progresses the program output grows as more gaps show up (i.e. current state)? Any need to detect a HHMM file that isn't there at HHMM but shows up late at HHMM+27? If you must be bash only, what about `find -name 'Test-\d\d\d\d.png' | sort | read ...` [or equiv]?

Comment: @CraigEstey If OP wants to list MISSING files then you somehow need to generate the list of all files including the missing ones. See my edit.

Comment: @CraigEstey In this case, what I expect are files like foo-0000.png, foo-0005.png ... foo-0055.png, foo-0100.png ... foo-2355.png, which at 23h 55m is my last file for that day. Each day's files get their own folder, not that it matters much. I figured it would be simple enough to generate each expected file name, and then test for its existence.

What makes `parallel` appealing is I can do this:

`parallel "something {1} {2}" ::: $(seq 0 23) ::: $(seq 0 5 55)`

And `parallel` will automatically Cartesian Product it all without a nested loop. If I can just the syntax right.

Comment: @OleTange Thank you for the edit which I just read. I like the {00..12} trick to eliminate the need for `printf` for the simple formatting. Having `printf` there was bothering me.

I would love to know how to eliminate duplicating 'Test-{1}{2}' for cases where file names are more complex, but this will handle my current problem.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to my simplified example in my edit ... this doesn't work

`parallel echo $(printf %02d {1}) ::: $(seq 1 10)`

... but this does

`parallel echo "\$(printf %02d {1})" ::: $(seq 1 10)`

The problem was I needed to escape that `$` so the expression would get evaluated by `parallel`, not by `bash`.

So the solution to my original question becomes

`parallel "file=\$(printf %s-%02d%02d.kml {1} {2} {3}) && [ -f \$file ] || echo \$file - Nope" ::: 'Foo' ::: $(seq 0 23) ::: $(seq 0 5 55)`

which additionally assigns the result of the `$(printf)` to a variable, so I don't have to call printf more than once. Even got it working when I assigned the `printf` command to a variable, in case I wanted to reuse it. So I think I'm good.

Thanks for the answer & comments guys.

Comment: @OleTange I am leaving your answer as Approved, since it had a bit more information than mine. Also I'm not sure approving your own answer is even allowed.